# Boot in same laptop Win 7 and 8 in 2 different HDD switching drives

Tags: boot

It is possible to boot Win 7 with one HDD, taking out it and switching another HDD with Win 8 in same Laptop.

Comment: If you did a clean install on both drives the respective OSes then I don't see why not.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I did this on my Dell D600 and on my Lenovo T-60. Had several drives with different OS's, XP, W7, W8, Ubuntu, Arch.

as long as you follow Darius advice to install the OS on that laptop and not use a hard drive from another laptop with a previously installed OS.